# Open RemixOS system.img on Windows and edit init.sh (Faulty Touchscreen)

Tags: touchscreen, android-x86

I installed RemixOS on my Baytrail Tablet but the touchscreen doesn't seem to work properly. It only works in the middle of the screen and the touches are registered 3-4 cm left of the area of touch. I have already tried everything I found by Googling like adding `rmmod i2c-hid` and `modprobe i2c-hid` with no luck.

But, recently under OS/BOM configuration in the BIOS I found 6 different options for the touch panel - MSSL, Ntrig, ChipOne, Focaltech, Goodix and Disable. I'd like to try each one of them, but I want rmmod and modprobe to run on every boot automatically.

I tried editing init.sh (in system/etc) with no luck. I am using Windows 7 right now. Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add your line of code into the init.sh file under Function_misc line 18